# CORS error despite Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in preflight response

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cors

Firefox and Chrome are giving me CORS error, even though the OPTIONS response contains `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

I'm curious what I need to do to make the OPTIONS preflight cors check pass?

Here are the requests and responses copied from both browsers.

```
% ## FIREFOX
% curl -i 'http://localhost:5000/sql/change_document_contents?id=1' -X OPTIONS -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:3000/' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000' -H 'Connection: keep-alive'
<ol-Request-Headers: content-type' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:3000/' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000' -H 'Connection: keep-alive'
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.9.5
Date: Sat, 29 May 2021 06:08:59 GMT
%
% ## CHROME
% curl 'http://localhost:5000/sql/change_document_contents?id=1' \
  -i \
  -X 'OPTIONS' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
  -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type' \
  -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Referer: http://localhost:3000/' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  --compressed
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.9.5
Date: Sat, 29 May 2021 06:12:11 GMT
```

As you can see, headers are there, but the CORS error still appears. Firefox gives the error CORS Missing Allow header on the preflight request, and NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI on the actual POST request. Whereas Chrome says "Cross origin resource sharing error: HeaderDisallowedByPreflightResponse"

Answer (score 10):

The response is missing an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header. In hindsight, the Chrome error message sort of points to this.

To fix, add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` to the response.